# time data does not match format error in robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am getting following error for datetime in robotframework:

> ValueError: time data '1609-38-90 78:55:36.030000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

Below is my code:

```
${lte_epoch_time}    Get Current Date    result_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the answer in your question itself. `'1609-38-90 78:55:36.030000'` is not a valid date format. Month can not be 38 and day 90 and hours 78. You need to clean your data set before any preprocessing